# Excel Pivot Table: Group rows and then average

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table, average

I'm hoping to find a way to sum rows and then average the summed data (in that order) using Excel. I'm looking to use PowerBI in the future but need a workaround in Excel for now.

The goal is to produce a table of average daily two-way traffic flows for each month for a number of locations. The raw data I have is broken down by location, date and flow direction ("in" or "out"). To produce an average daily two-way flow I need to sum the two directions for each day and location respectively and then average the resulting two-way flows for each month. The raw data is in the following format: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU3Is.jpg

I initially thought this was a fairly simple pivot table job but I've consistently hit the same hurdle each time - being able to sum the two directions ('in' and 'out') before then averaging the resulting two-way flows for each month. A simple pivot table average produces 1-way averages so the key appears to be summing AND THEN averaging. Any suggestions for how to do this in Excel would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Not seen your data, but sumifs() should do.

Comment: If @SolarMike suggestion of sumifs doesn't work, you can probably do this in Power Query. Please post data as text and desired results as either text or a screenshot. Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).